Manhwa where the class gets isekaied and then they all ask the goddess what happens to their family, but the main character asks to go back
When he asks to go back home, she teleports him in front of everyone, saying she teleported him back home, but she actually teleported him to a territory of monsters and none of his classmates know.

Could this be "Is This Hero For Real?"

Kang Hansoo was summoned to this world with his classmates.
His classmates were amazed by this brand new world and the magic in
it, but the only thing Hansoo wanted to do was quickly return home.
“Why would I give up my warm, comfortable house to have an adventure
in this world…?
Even the goddess that summoned me said that if I wasn’t willing to,
there was nothing she could do to force me and promised to return me
to my original world.
She did teleport me, but…
When I opened my eyes, I was still in this world!
All of my friends were gone, and the only thing around me was
monsters!!
A goddess tricked me…?
How do I get back home now…?
More than that, how do I survive here…?!“


She claims he's being transported back to Earth, but in reality she dumps him into a realm of powerful monsters, evidently expecting him to die.




And if so, it's a dupe of Manga where the main character is tricked by a goddess and given the 'curse of the hero'

This was my first thought.

@DavidW - It's a fairly tropey description. The answer below could easily be what OP is thinking of, although I do reckon it's this one.

@Valorum agreed, yours matches better with "says she will send him home".

There is little details, but Failure Frame: I Became the Strongest and Annihilated Everything with Low-Level Spells mostly matches.

Touka Mimori and his classmates are suddenly summoned to a fantasy
world by a goddess to act as heroes. While most of them are shown to
have exceptional skills, Mimori has an E-rank. Deeming him useless,
the goddess decides to banish Mimori to a monster-filled dungeon where
nobody has ever survived, a fate to which almost all of his classmates
abandon him without hesitation. However, it turns out that his skills
are more abnormal and powerful than they seem. After escaping from the
dungeon, Mimori vows to have his revenge. As he travels throughout
this new world, strengthening and increasing his skills, he acquires
friends and allies while making sure that the goddess and his former
classmates continue to believe him dead.

